# DAX Measure: True/False for selected column names

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

How to write measure that could filter Matrix based on `True` values in selected column names?

**Example ([**download**](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/HowToSliceTrueColumnnames.pbix)):**
[image]

Estimated result: want to see only rows with `Football = True`

P.S. `Field parameters`  are used to create slicer with column names

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix this in the data model by introducing a Customer_Sport linking table with bi-directional cross-filtering to Customer.

Comment: Yes, it's standard approach. Just curious if it's possible to avoid "unnecessary" tables using DAX.